# PHP - hyperlink in statement

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink

How can I insert a hyperlink into the following PHP statement:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['A'].$record['B'].</a>."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

I am creating a table with one column. I want to create a link so that when the text on any row is clicked, it opens the page on the hyperlink.

Where would I insert the hyperlink in the statement? The link is constant.

Records 'A' and 'B' are from an SQL select query.

Comment: Is it a different link for each row - or one constant link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy and paste this code on the place of your given code. it will work.

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='test.php'>".$record['A'].$record['B']."</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['A'].$record['B'].</a>."</td>"; //Here you should get some error
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

You should add an [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tag

```
echo "<td><a href='".$record['A'].$record['B']."'>Somenametodisplay</a>"."</td>";
```

For Dynamic text you should replace the value with `Somenametodisplay`

So you will be having

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='".$record['A'].$record['B']."'>Somenametodisplay</a>"."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Or if you want to want to show it the values in the name then

```
 while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='yourpath'>".$record['A'].$record['B']."</a>"."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Records A and B represent text as they are from an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='#'>{$record['A']} {$record['B']}</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid simply dumping code, you should provide an explanation too where you can.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a property "link" in your db table - try something like this:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="'.$record['link'].'">'.$record['A'].$record['B'].'</a></td>';
echo '</tr>';}
```

And if you want to link the whole row you can use a js handler like this:

```
echo '<tr onClick="document.location.href=\''.$record['link'].'\'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single link on each row:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='urlhere'>".$record['A'].$record['B']."</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

As you've stated that it's a constant link on every row why not apply it to the entire table instead? That way you're not having unnecessary code bloating your table.

Just wrap the entire table in the link, so something like this:

```
echo "<a href='urlhere'>";
echo "<table>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['A'].$record['B']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, when trying your first answer, I receive the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'